# cmake rejects certain cflags

Tags: cmake

I have here a project - though I believe it's independent of the package used - that, when configured with

`cmake -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE="-O2 -msse"`

uses those exact flags. However, as soon as I use

`cmake -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE="-O2 -msse -fmessage-length=0"`

cmake goes to stubborn state and ignores my desired flags, instead defaulting to the project's defaults. This is even reflected in `CMakeCache.txt`, though I do not know what to make of it.

```
CMakeCache.txt:CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG
CMakeCache.txt:CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-O2 -msse -fmessage-length:UNINITIALIZED=0
```

The question on the table is — how do I get my flags used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [is a known bug in the command line parsing in CMake](http://www.vtk.org/Bug/view.php?id=9214). It's getting confused with the extra = sign and thinks the variable name is `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-O2 -msse -fmessage-length` with the value `0`!

One way to get the option in the cache in the correct format is to use the cache editor. After running cmake initially, run `make edit_cache` then press <kbd>t</kbd> to toggle advanced options, <kbd>Ctrl-n</kbd> down to the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE` option, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to edit it and type in the value you want. After that type <kbd>c</kbd> then <kbd>g</kbd> to configure and generate the Makefiles.

Alternatively, just edit the cache with your $EDITOR and enter the correct line:

```
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O2 -msse -fmessage-length=0
```

This isn't very elegant, but it should get you motoring.

Answer (score 2):

BTW, the type declaration also works from the command line, e.g.:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING="-O2 -msse -fmessage-length=0"
```

should work. Still kind of awkward though.